# SharePoint List Syncing Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

[image: Screenshot]

I am reaching out regarding a challenge I've encountered with a SharePoint list on our team site.

I recently created a SharePoint team site and configured a list within it, which I connected to a Power App for record management. As the owner with full control in SharePoint as well as power apps , I've noticed that despite successful updates through Power Apps, the SharePoint list is stuck in a perpetual "Syncing" state at the same time Power App gallery is showing all these details including attachments.

I've given it ample time, waiting for three days, but the issue persists. To rule out site-wide problems, I created a few additional lists within the same site, and they function correctly. It seems to be specific to this particular list, I request your support to overcome this issue